# (Error 11 444) Weird problem with Apple Music downloads on multiple macbooks

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, icloud, macos, apple-music

Here's my problem which is driving me nuts:
Me and my wife have an Apple Music family membership. Since some days, I cannot download Apple Music songs to my computer and/or add them to my library. It only succeeds like 10% and after a lengthy period of time.
The rest of the times i get Error 11 444
None of these problems appear on my iPhone. But exactly the same problem appears on my wife's MacBook.
Can it be something with our local network? No changes have been made to it since 1 year or something.
Also, I tried briefly using my MacBook with my iPhone's cellular network and got the same problem.

Both MacBooks run Sierra.

Comment: Have you messed with the hosts files on your macs to block an Apple Server, flushed DNS or even changed the DNS servers? Try 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as DNS servers (Google DNS). To flush, Open the Terminal
Navigate to Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal
Flush DNS - Type the following command and hit enter.
`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203244 For more.

Comment: This seems to be the issue because error 444 is typically a connection closed without response. Try putting one of your macs in the DMZ on your network, and see if it works (this will expose it completely to the internet, bypassing all router settings).

Comment: thank you but it doesn't seem to work.. The bug is very weird because I also get similar problems with Safari (when accessing iTunes Connect) and with Xcode (when trying to upload an app)

Comment: Try typing in the shell `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, then try to find any Apple domains (if there are any, delete the line. After, press CONTROL X, not command x, press y and return. It will ask for your password, but it is a standard thing, because you are changing a file as root.

Comment: I get only these three: localhost, broadcasthost, localhost. I was able to overcome the problem by using Application Loader and editing its net.properties to use port 80 instead of 443 for https. But the problem remains for all the other areas: Safari and iTunes